# How can I show/hide contact information based on U.S. State selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery

At my company, certain representatives service a variety of states. I'm trying to create a dropdown that will show/hide a their contact information based on the U.S. State that a user selects. I have tried a variety of ways and it works if I use 3 options, but it doesn't work when I try to add all 50 states.

Is there a problem with my code? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

```js
 $('#purpose').on('change', function() {
      
   if ( this.value == 'blank')
      {
        $("#blank").show();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#blank").hide();
      }
   
   if ( this.value == 'jy')
      {
        $("#jess").show();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#jess").hide();
      }
      
       if ( this.value == 'jp')
      {
        $("#justin").show();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#justin").hide();
      }
      
        if ( this.value == 'rs')
      {
        $("#rob").show();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#rob").hide();
      }
   
    if ( this.value == 'rys')
      {
        $("#ryan").show();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#ryan").hide();
      }
   
    if ( this.value == 'ss')
      {
        $("#ssco").show();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#ssco").hide();
      }
    });
});
```

```html
 <div>                        
                              <select id='purpose'>
                                    <option value="blank">--</option>
                                    <option value="rys">Alabama</option>
                                    <option value="ss">Alaska</option>
                                    <option value="jy">Arizona</option>
                                    <option value="rys">Arkansas</option>
                                   <option value="jy">California</option>
                                    <option value="ss">Colorado</option>
                                    <option value="jp">Connecticut</option>
                                    <option value="jp">Delaware</option>
                                    <option value="rys">Florida</option>
                                    <option value="rys">Georgia</option>
                                    <option value="ss">Hawaii</option>
                                    <option value="jy">Idaho</option>
                                    <option value="rs">Illinois</option>
                                    <option value="rs">Indiana</option>
                                    <option value="rs">Iowa</option>
                                    <option value="ss">Kansas</option>
                                    <option value="jp">Kentucky</option>
                                    <option value="rys">Louisiana</option>
                                    <option value="jp">Maine</option>
                                    <option value="jp">Maryland</option>
                                  <option value="jp">Massachusetts</option>
                                 <option value="rs">Michigan</option>
                                    <option value="rs">Minnesota</option>
                                    <option value="rys">Mississippi</option>
                                    <option value="rs">Missouri</option>
                                    <option value="jy">Montana</option>
                                    <option value="ss">Nebraska</option>
                                    <option value="jy">Nevada</option>
                                    <option value="jp">New Hampshire</option>
                                    <option value="jp">New Jersey</option>
                                    <option value="ss">New Mexico</option>
                                    <option value="jp">New York</option>
                                    <option value="rys">North Carolina</option>
                                    <option value="ss">North Dakota</option>
                                    <option value="rs">Ohio</option>
                                    <option value="ss">Oklahoma</option>
                                 <option value="jy">Oregon</option>
                                    <option value="jp">Pennsylvania</option>
                                    <option value="jp">Rhode Island</option>
                                    <option value="rys">South Carolina</option>
                                    <option value="ss">South Dakota</option>
                                    <option value="rys">Tennessee</option>
                                    <option value="ss">Texas</option>
                                    <option value="jy">Utah</option>
                                    <option value="jp">Vermont</option>
                                    <option value="rys">Virginia</option>
                                    <option value="jy">Washington</option>
                                    <option value="jp">West Virginia</option>
                                    <option value="rs">Wisconsin</option>
                                    <option value="jy">Wyoming</option>
                             </select>
                          
     <div style='display:none;' id='blank'>
    Select Your State
  </div>                          
   
  <div style='display:none;' id='jess'> NAME 1 <br>
    PHONE <br>
    <a href="mailto:#">EMAIL</a>
</div>

<div style='display:none;' id='justin'> NAME 2 <br>
    PHONE <br>
    <a href="mailto:#">EMAIL</a>
</div>

<div style='display:none;' id='rob'> NAME 3 <br>
    PHONE<br>
    <a href="mailto:#">EMAIL</a>
  </div>
  
  <div style='display:none;' id='ryan'> NAME 4 <br>
    PHONE <br>
    <a href="mailto:#">EMAIL</a>
  </div>
  
  <div style='display:none;' id='ssco'> Please contact your local <a href="#">sales representative</a>.
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You have a `SyntaxError`, check the console.

Comment: You forgot to include jQuery in your snippet and you have an extra `});
` in your example.

Comment: Have a look at the *switch* statement...

Comment: This could probably help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43899842/how-can-i-summarise-javascript-code-block/43900407#43900407

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this. I see the extra }); but I'm not sure what I would include regarding jQuery for this. Do I need to write something new?

Comment: I'm just saying that in your snippet, you forgot to include jQuery, so it won;t run. Checkout the options on the left when editing the snippet in your question. Also in your actual code did you include jQuery? What errors do you get in your actual code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the way you are doing this isn't really good for a number of reasons.  It's very inflexible and requires that you change both your HTML and Javascript whenever your staff assignments change.

Here's how I approached this.  I have an array-like object with staff (like you might retrieve from a database), and the staff have contact info and a list of states they are associated with.  When the user chooses a state, we look at each "rep" and see if they service that state and add them to the displayed list if so.  If you need to change the assignments around, you just need to edit that one object.

```js
var reps = {
  Justin: {
    states: ["AL", "AR"],
    contact: { name: "Justin", phone: "555-123-4567" }
  },
  Jess: {
    states: ["AR", "MS", "LA"],
    contact: { name: "Jess", phone: "555-234-5678" }
  },
  Rob: {
    states: ["NC", "SC"],
    contact: { name: "Rob", phone: "555-345-6789" }
  }
};

$("#state").on("change", function() {  
  $("#repList").hide();
  $("#repList").html("");

  var selectedState = $(this).val();
  if (!selectedState) {
    $("#reps").fadeOut();
    return;
  }
  $("#reps").fadeIn();
  var noReps = true;
  Object.keys(reps).forEach(function(repKey) {
    var rep = reps[repKey];
    if (rep.states.includes(selectedState)) {
      noReps = false;
      $("#repList").append(
        "<li>" + rep.contact.name + " - " + rep.contact.phone + "</li>"
      );
    }
  });
  if (noReps) {
    $("#noReps").show();
  } else {
    $("#noReps").hide();
  }

  $("#repList").fadeIn();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app" class="container">
  <h1>Choose your state</h1>
  <select id="state" class="form-control">
      <option></option>
      <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
      <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
      <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
      <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
      <option value="CA">California</option>
      <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
      <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
      <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
      <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
      <option value="FL">Florida</option>
      <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
      <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
      <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
      <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
      <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
      <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
      <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
      <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
      <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
      <option value="ME">Maine</option>
      <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
      <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
      <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
      <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
      <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
      <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
      <option value="MT">Montana</option>
      <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
      <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
      <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
      <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
      <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
      <option value="NY">New York</option>
      <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
      <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
      <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
      <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
      <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
      <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
      <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
      <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
      <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
      <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
      <option value="TX">Texas</option>
      <option value="UT">Utah</option>
      <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
      <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
      <option value="WA">Washington</option>
      <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
      <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
      <option value="WY">Wyoming</option> 
    </select>
  <br>
  <div>
    <div style="display:none" id="reps">
      <h2>State Reps</h2>
      <hr>
      <h3 id="noReps" style="display:none">
          Sorry there are no reps for your state
        </h3>
      <ul id="repList"></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/imjosh/pen/wdmyKv?editors=1010

Comment: In google chrome, press F12 on your keyboard to open developer tools.  In the console you will see an error.  You will need to learn how to use developer tools if you're going to do web programming (pro tip).  From experience, I know that error message means that jQuery isn't loaded.  You are loading jquery on your page at the end of the body tag (good), but you've put the new code in the head tag (not recommended), so jquery hasn't loaded yet when it runs.  You need to move the <script>code</script> to after the one that loads jquery.

Comment: You are my f*ing hero, dude! This task has been plaguing me for too long. Thank you so much!

Comment: awesome, looks good! FYI you will need to polyfill array.includes for the code to work in older browsers (like <= IE 11). Search SO or post another question on how to do that if you don't know.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#purpose').on('change', function(){
 $(".somemainclass").hide();
 $("#"+this.value).show();
 });
```

Why not simply assign the input values to the element ids?

```
<div id="jy" class="somemainclass"> </div>
```